# Emulating a heterogenous system, like an ARM Processor with P and E Cores

Tags: linux, arm, emulation, qemu

I'm trying to emulate a processor which consists processor cores with different max frequencies per core, like ARM processors or newer Intel processors which have a couple of Performance Cores and Efficiency Cores.

I tried it with Qemu, but I only didn't get far, the only thing I found was [qemu-system-aarch64](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/qemu-system-arm/qemu-system-aarch64.1.en.html) where you can configure cores per die and die count using nema but i did't find a possibilty to change frequency or core architechture for a specific die. Is it even possible with qemu or is there a alternative? Preferably the emulation should be able to run linux.

For clarification, I'm trying to show that on a heterogeneus system i.e. a processor with different core speeds a certain framework works better then another one.

Comment: I thought that in most such systems, even if some cores are faster or slower than others, they are all architecturally identical, so that processes and threads can be transparently moved between them.  And qemu, not being a cycle-accurate emulator, does not emulate the speed of a CPU, only its architectural behavior.  So I don't know what there would be to emulate.  But maybe you have something else in mind?

Comment: Or do you just want it to support the hardware mechanisms that query these things, and have it return some arbitrary values of your choosing?

Comment: Oh good to know, I didn't know that qemu doesn't emulate cycles, do you know an emulator which supports it? As I added to the description I'm trying to show that a Framework A behaves better on processors with different core speeds than Framework B.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. A cycle-accurate emulator is a much different beast because it requires a precise specification of not only the architecture but also the microarchitecture, and the latter is often proprietary.  My impression is that they are mostly created for much older and simpler machines (e.g. classic video games, where the timing has to be exact in order for the gameplay to be right), which have been thoroughly reverse-engineered.

Comment: You might be able to get such a thing as closed-source commercial software from the core vendor.  Something like [Intel SDE](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/software-development-emulator.html), perhaps.  But I suspect it will be simpler to just try to get access to actual hardware of the appropriate kind.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try the Intel SDE, unfortunately i don't have enough time to get my hands on real hardware

Comment: I am not actually sure if Intel SDE does this, you'll have to check.  I recall there being some sort of product like this from Intel, but I may be misremembering, or it may be something other than SDE.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to [Nate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634919/nate-eldredge) I found [Intel Simics](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/simics-simulator.html) which is able to simulate heterogeneous systems.